# Dynamically post post_id and user auth id for comment like system where comment form display as popup to comment each post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am creating a comment system where user can comment each post, when user click comment button popup box will appear with multiple field, form is posted to db from jquery, i have a problem that i can't store post_id and user auth id to db through jquery formData method

```
   @foreach($customerposts as $customerpost)
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data- 
   target="#maskup-{{$customerpost->id}}" style="float:right;  margin- 
   top:50px;" id="bidnow" value="{{$customerpost->id}}">Comment 
   Now</button>
   @include('forms.commentform')
   @endforeach
```

comment form
       
       created form field 
       display correct post id and user id here
       passed through hidden field also it doesn't work

```
   </form>

    >jquery
    $( 'form' ).submit(function ( e ) {
    var data;
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('message', $("#message").val());
    data.append('hidden', $("#hidden").val()); can't get this value from 
    controller         
    // console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
        url: 'api/comment/',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        });
```

i want to post post_id and user id dynamically for each post

**my controller**

```
public function Bidpost(Request $request)
    {    

      $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [`enter code here`
        'message'=>'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
        }

        $bidon = new ContributerBidOn();
        $bidon->user_id = '5'; //can;t het user id from hidden field
        $bidon->post_id = '8';

        $bidon->Guarantee_Of_Product = $request['message'];

        $bidon->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Data is successfully added']);
    }
}
Route api
Route::post('/bidon/','BidController@Bidpost');
```

Comment: This whole thing is just a formatting nightmare. Please clean up your post so it's readable please.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to understand what you wanted to do here. But I guess you are unable to send **post id** and **authenticated user id** in ajax.

My suggestion will be while you click for the comment you can get the post id from the button as you have the id present in button **value="{{$customerpost->id}}"** value by

> add btnForComments class to your button inside for loop and remove the id attribute

```
$(".btnForComments").click( function() {
 var postId = $(this).val();
 });
```

> Remove id **bidnow** from the button in your for a loop. As id should be unique inside DOM.

For authenticated user-id you do not have to send it or keep it hidden inputs in ajax as you can get it from Session in your Controller directly.
Else you can assign the id to a javascript variable and pass it in ajax. The authenticated use id will be the same for all comments though.